# How to use if/ifelse on dplyr's group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there anyway to apply a conditional group_by? For example (code DOESN'T work btw but its just to show the iris dataset so you get the gist):

```
iris$Sepal.Width.r <- round(iris$Sepal.Width)
for(i in 1:2){
test <- iris %>% 
  ifelse(i == 1, group_by(Species), group_by(Sepal.Width.r)) %>% #****
  summarise(avgLWdiff = (mean(Petal.Length) - mean(Petal.Width)))
  print(test)
}
```

The starred line #**** is my very rough (and wrong) guess on what it should look like. I think the questions I've seen from others so far ask about the if statement within the summarise/mutate line but I haven't seen anyone ask about the group_by line. Also, the contents within my summarise takes up a few lines.

My desired output is:

when i==1:

```
Species    avgLWdiff 
<fct>          <dbl> 
1 setosa         1.22 
2 versicolor      2.93 
3 virginica       3.53
```

when i == 2:

```
Sepal.Width.r avgLWdiff
<dbl>     <dbl>
1             2      2.76
2             3      2.76
3             4      1.54
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  can you show your desired output?  you set i as 1 and thereafter checking whether it is 1.  Too confusing

Comment: @AnilGoyal I just set it as 1 as an example. My script is a huge for loop. I'll add the for loop to my example. My end result should be the summarise results.

Comment: the question will be clear, if you will include a desired output too.  You have only included a partial code and except that partial code nothing is there.  How can one understand the question?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over each column in the data set to determine avgLWdiff? @user2554330 seems to have a working example that does what you're asking, but the workflow you've got here appears to be "untidy." Other than some hard coded if else params, can you describe what the for loop is doing for you?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion over my question...I tried to recreate the issue using a common dataset even though the setup doesn't seem to make sense or seem useful. I'll keep the "usefulness" in mind in future questions.
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using `if`, not `ifelse`.  Remember that `if` is the one to use for control flow, which is what you want.

```
iris %>% 
   {if(i == 1) group_by(., Species) else group_by(., Sepal.Width.r)} %>% 
   summarise(avgLWdiff = (mean(Petal.Length) - mean(Petal.Width)))
```

Here I've put the `if` clause in `{}`, because otherwise the pipe would try to put `iris` in as the test.  By using the `{}` the magrittr pipe looks deeper for the dot.

Doing this with the base pipe is harder, because it's less flexible.  I think you need to define a small helper function to get it to work:

```
 f <- function(d){if(i == 1) group_by(d, Species) else group_by(d, Sepal.Width.r)}
 iris |> f() |>
   summarise(avgLWdiff = (mean(Petal.Length) - mean(Petal.Width)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem. I am using the pipe from `dplyr` but you can replace it with the built-in pipe and you will get the same result.

```
for(i in 1:2){
  test <- iris %>% 
    group_by(across(all_of(if(i==1) "Species" else "Sepal.Width.r"))) %>%  
    summarise(avgLWdiff = (mean(Petal.Length) - mean(Petal.Width)))
  print(test)
}

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Species    avgLWdiff
#   <fct>          <dbl>
# 1 setosa          1.22
# 2 versicolor      2.93
# 3 virginica       3.53

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Sepal.Width.r avgLWdiff
#           <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1             2      2.76
# 2             3      2.76
# 3             4      1.54
```